# Why does the wait() method not trigger notifyAll()?

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

I'm new to Java multithreading and written a small program to test how the wait() and notifyAll() methods interact with each other. But why doesn't this program work?

```
package sample;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Thread(new MyWriter()).start();
            new Thread(new MyReader()).start();
        }
    }
    
    class MyReader implements Runnable {
    
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            while(true) {
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
    
    class MyWriter implements Runnable {
    
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
           

     System.out.println("Waiting...");
                wait();
                System.out.println("Wait Terminated");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running, I expected the output to be

```
Waiting...
Wait Terminated
```

But it outputs

```
Waiting...
```

And just waits forever until I terminate it manually.

Comment: You need to wait/notify on a common object.  You could simply create an instance of `Object` and pass it to both threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `notify` call notifies the objects waiting on the monitor of an object. So, if you issue `wait` on an object, you have to `notify` using the same object.

One way to do this is to simply use a shared object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Object lock=new Object();
     new Thread(new MyWriter(lock)).start();
     new Thread(new MyReader(lock)).start();
}
```

Then:

```
public void run() {
 while(true) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
 }

public void run() {
   while(true) {
      try {
         synchronized(lock) {        
             System.out.println("Waiting...");
             lock.wait();
             System.out.println("Wait Terminated");
         }
      } ...
}
```

Comment: @SolomonSlow, both threads are running enabled loops. `notify` will eventually wake up the other thread.

Comment: Oops! Never mind.